# Are multiple producers/consumers on the same WebSocket connection with Apache Pulsar, when using React Native?

Tags: react-native, websocket, apache-pulsar

Languages that do not have a client library provided by Apache Pulsar can communicate with it using WebSocket. If WebSocket is used in, for example, React Native, the producer WebSocket connection gets established using something like:

`new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/ws/v2/producer/persistent/public/default/**my-topic**?producerName=my-topic-producer');`

and similarly, a consumer connection to another topic using:

`new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/ws/v2/consumer/persistent/public/default/**my-other-topic**?subscriptionType=Exclusive&consumerName=my-other-topic-consumer');`

That is to say, one has to specify the url upto, at the least, the topic when creating a new connection.

Do the two calls create two WebSocket connections with (the Pulsar's WebSocket component (whether embedded or independent) running on) the server? Concerned because that would mean multiple WebSocket connections for each instance of my React Native app running on a user's device.